# What's the best way to complete this task in php oop

Tags: php, oop

#### SPECIFICATION

I have been asked to create a new PHP class library (any PHP version) to help me manage my fish tank. The library should satisfy the following user stories and demonstrate testing abilities.

Here are the user stories:

•   A user should be able to add 3 types of fish to the tank (Gold fish, Angel fish, Babel fish) and name the fish 
•   A user should be able to see how much food to put in the tank with a Feed() method. 
    This should return the weight in grams of the total required fish food.
•   A user should be able to save the data about the fish in the tank to a JSON file 
•   Ensure the design allows me to add more types of fish in the future without having to change the tank library.
    o   0.1g for each Gold fish 
    o   0.2g for each Angel fish 
    o   0.3g for each Babel fish

#### MY ATTEMPT

```
## CLASSES ##

    # Tank Class (Parent) // # DEFINES EMPTY TANK
class Tank {
    # Member variables
    // Set default unique ID (allows duplicates of Name)
    protected $ID = 'undefined';
    // Set default Type
    protected $type = 'notype';
    // Set default Name
    protected $name = 'unnamed';
    // Set default Appetite
    protected $appetite = 0;        
}//end class Tank
# Fish Class (Child of Tank) // # DEFINE FISH TYPES (GROUP)
class Fish extends Tank {
    # Member functions
    // setting ID
    function setID($par){$this->ID = $par;}//end function
    // getting ID
    function getID(){$FishID = $this->ID;}//end function
    // setting Type
    function setType($par){$this->type = $par;}//end function
    // getting Type
    function getType(){$FishType = $this->type;}//end function
    // setting Name
    function setName($par){$this->name = $par;}//end function
    // getting Name
    function getName(){$FishName = $this->name;}//end function
    // setting Appetite
    function setAppetite($par){$this->appetite = $par;}//end function
    // getting Appetite
    function getAppetite(){$FishAppetite = $this->appetite;}//end function
}//end class Fish
$Tank = array();

## Functions ##
# Print Array Function // FOR TESTING
function see($array){print('<pre>');print_r($array);print('</pre>');}//end Function

# Add Fish Function 
function Add($Fish){
    # Instantiating our Fish
    $NewFish = new Fish;
    # Giving our Fish a unique ID
    $NewFish->setID( $Fish['ID'] );
    # Naming our Fish
    $NewFish->setName( $Fish['Name'] );
    # Classifying our Fish
    $NewFish->setType( $Fish['Type'] );
    # Preparing our Fish's Diet
    $NewFishAppetite = $Fish['Appetite'];
    # Setting Diets for our fish
    $NewFish->setAppetite( $Fish['Appetite'] );
    # Display New Fish Data
    see($NewFish);
    # Return New Fish Data
    return $NewFish;
}//end Function AddNewFish
# Feed Function 
function Feed($TankData){
    // Set Default amount of fish food at zero
    $FoodAccumulator = 0;
    // set array counter
    $counter = 0;
    // count how many array items
    $counted = count($TankData);
    // while counter is less than counted...
    while ($counter < $counted){
        // add each Appetite value to the Acuumulator
        $FoodAccumulator = ($FoodAccumulator + $TankData[$counter]['Appetite']);
        // increment counter
        $counter++;
    }//end while
    //return the weight in grams of the total required fish food
    return $FoodAccumulator.' grams';
}//end function Feed()
# Write json Function 
function jsonWrite($jsonMyFile,$Array){
    file_put_contents($jsonMyFile,json_encode($Array));
}// end jsonWrite Function
# Read json Function 
function jsonRead($jsonMyFile){
    // copy file content into a string var
    $json_file = file_get_contents($jsonMyFile);
    // convert the string to a json object
    $JsonFileObject = json_decode($json_file);
    // return the json object
    return $JsonFileObject;
}//end jsonRead Function




// let's build the Tank and add some fish...
// DEFINING SINGLE FISH
########################################################################################
### New Fish Template ###
// Design Fish
$Fish = array("ID"=>"0","Name"=>"Test Fish","Type"=>"TestFish","Appetite"=>"0.9");
// Add Fish to Tank
Add($Fish);
// Update Tank Data
array_push($Tank,$Fish);
########################################################################################


### New Fish 1 ###
$Fish = array("ID"=>"1","Name"=>"Mr Gold","Type"=>"Goldfish","Appetite"=>"0.1");// Design
Add($Fish);// Add
array_push($Tank,$Fish);// Update
### New Fish 2 ###
$Fish = array("ID"=>"2","Name"=>"Miss Angel","Type"=>"Angelfish","Appetite"=>"0.2");// Design
Add($Fish);// Add
array_push($Tank,$Fish);// Update
### New Fish 3 ###
$Fish = array("ID"=>"3","Name"=>"Hitch","Type"=>"Babelfish","Appetite"=>"0.3");// Design
Add($Fish);// Add
array_push($Tank,$Fish);// Update


// CALCULATE TOTAL FEED
echo '<hr/>'.Feed($Tank).'<hr/>';

php // json file i/o
// define json file
$jsonMyFile = 'tank.json';// chmod 0666

// write Tank data to json file
echo '<hr/>writing json<hr/>';
jsonWrite($jsonMyFile,$Tank);

// TESTING
// read Tank data from json file
echo '<hr/>reading json<hr/>';
see(jsonRead($jsonMyFile));

php exit();

###############################
```

Apologies in advance for being a newbie

Comment: This is a question forum, we answer specific questions and try to solve specific problems. This isn't a "Fix my code, these are my requirements" service

Comment: Thanks Loek but I wasn't expecting anyone to "Fix my code" as you put it. I was in fact hoping for a brief answer that would set me on the right track or at least point out the wrongs in my solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah well, then I just misinterpreted your question. I'll put some tips in an answer

Comment: Much appreciated. I probably didn't explain myself as best as I could of and apologies again as this was in fact my first ever post here. I am a brand newbie on here and almost a brand newbie to OOP in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOP is all about classes that are responsible for a (real-world) thing. The `Tank` class is such one so that's okay.

However `Fish` can never be a subclass of `Tank` since they don't resemble nearly the same thing. `Gold Fish`, `Angel Fish` or `Babel Fish` can be subclasses of `Fish`, since they are actually fish with a little bit more detailed information than just a fish. A `Fish` isn't detailed `Tank`, so it can't be a subclass.

I would start refactoring your code by doing the following:

1. Make `Fish` it's own class and let `Gold Fish`, `Angel Fish` and `Babel Fish` extend it
2. Add a field to your `Tank` class that keeps track of which `Fish` are in it. For example: `protected $fishInTank = Array();`
3. Add a method that lets you add & delete fish to your tank (thus adds a record to your array!):

   ```
   public addFishToTank(Fish $fish)
   {
       array_push($fishInTank, $fish);
   }
   ```

There is ofcourse lots of steps after this, but I hope I've set you on the right course. OOP is a bit of a hassle at first, and it often is a bit more effort to code. On the other hand, your code is quite readable and if done right, very easily extendible and maintainable.

Good luck! (and please don't forget to tick as an answer if it was helpful ;) )

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Loek. I will work on this and post my next attempt. I was struggling to see where the Tank fits in but now it makes a lot more sense. Legend! (answer ticked!)

Comment: And class `Fish` can be made abstract with a private constructor .. To make it a bit more complete :)

Comment: Glad I could help @Shonno! And didn't even think about that @dbf good tip!

Comment: K Loek, RE: "3. Add a method that lets you add & delete fish to your tank...". 
two things here I am unsure of; 
1) where am I putting this method?
2) can you please explain about the "(Fish" part of addFishToTank(Fish $fish)? I've never seen this sort of thing before.

Thanks again in advance. :)

Comment: @Loek
     `class Tank {
 # Member variables
 // Set storage
 protected $fishInTank = array();
 public function addFishToTank($fish)
 {
  array_push($fishInTank, $fish); // this is line 118
 }
}//end Tank class

/* I get an error when trying to add Bob to the tank */

$BobData = array("Fish_Name"=>$Bob->Fish_Name,"Fish_Type"=>$Bob->Fish_Type,"Fish_Appetite"=>$Bob->Fish_Appetite);

$Bob = Tank::addFishToTank($BobData);

// Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given ... line 118`
Q)- What am I doing wrong here?